# Bind the Array to comboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have `datagridviewComboboxColumn` I want to bind the array as dataSource to that column, In that array I have some data. I did this this task but whenever control leaving from `DGVCBX` cell data will invisible, I cant see the data. So how can I do this?

My task is How to Bind the Array of data to `datagridviewComboboxColumn`.

Comment: @ChrisShepherd this is not possible duplicate. The OP trying to add items to `comboBox` using the `array`

Comment: There's no mentioned `datagridviewComboboxColumn` in the suggested _possible duplicate question_. try to figure out. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] arr = { "test", "let", "go" };
        yourComboboxColumn1.DataSource = arr.ToArray(); //or .ToList();
```